# Change picture on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code with monitor size

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills large">
<li><a href="#19" data-toggle="tab">19</a></li>
<li><a href="#22" data-toggle="tab">22</a></li>
<li class="measure"><h4>inch <br>monitor</h4></li>
</ul>
```

now i want when user click on some size that picture change...

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<img src="img/pic1" class="img-responsive" alt="netbox2">
```

that is code for my picture..

I try with this jquery but it don't work.

```
<script>
$('classname').click(function() {
    $('.filter').removeClass('classname');
    $(this).addClass('classname');
});
</script>
```

how to use that data-toogle atributes?
Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XMSGe/78/)

I want when i click on first radio button to see only fisrt picture, on second other picture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is toggleClass("classname").

```
$("img").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('classname');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the `data-toggle` attribute simply do . .

```
$("#element").attr("data-toggle");
```

With the value you can then do

```
$('classname').click(function() {
    dataToggle = $("#element").attr("data-toggle");
    if(dataToggle == "foo"){
        //do this
    } else {
        //do this instead
    }
});
```

More info on [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .small {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
 }
 .medium {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
 }
 .large {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
 }
</style>
<input type="radio" data-target="small" class="image-size" name="image"/> small <br/>
<input type="radio" data-target="medium" class="image-size" name="image"/> medium <br/>
<input type="radio" data-target="large" class="image-size" name="image"/> large <br/>
<img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/524/web_2/512/facebook.png" class="img-responsive"/>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.image-size').on('click',function(){
        $('.img-responsive').removeClass().addClass('img-responsive').addClass($(this).data('target'));
        });

    })
</script>
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/mannejkumar/fbkvd/
Let me know if this doesn't meet your requirement